# Find probability of combination of two uniform variates

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

$X \sim R(0, 2)$, $Y \sim R(0, 5)$, X and Y are independent, I need to find $P(|X-Y| \leq 1)$

Comment: What does $R(a, b)$ stand for?

Comment: @YaniorWeg Rectangular/Uniform distribution presumably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "R(a,b)" is the uniform distribution of a< x< b, this situation can be modeled by the rectangle in an xy-coordinate system with vertices (0, 0), (2, 0), (0,5), and (2,5).  That has total area 2*5= 10.  |x- y|= 1 is the same as x- y= 1 so y= x- 1, and y- x= 1 so y= x+ 1.  Those are parallel lines.  The region in which |x- y|< 1 is the region between those two lines.  It has area 3.5 so the probability is 3.5/10= 0.35.